# Is it worth picking up Chaos in Greed Mode?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

So Chaos is a really neat passive item that causes future items to be chosen from random item pools. Basically that means any item can appear anywhere at anytime until that specific item pool is depleted.

I'm wondering if it's worth buying Chaos when it shows up in Greed Mode. Greed Mode's items already seem to be pulled randomly from item pools. For example, items that show up only in an angel or devil room in the main game are often available in the Greed Mode shops. So is it worth spending money to buy Chaos in Greed Mode? Does it actually do anything?

Comment: yesyesyes. I don't have time for an extensive answer now (Need to look up stuff) But the items in the shops are still based on specific pools, and chaos really helps with finding more devil/angel stuff.(there will be for example always be a shopitem in the greed shop, chaos in your case right now), with chaos this gets randomly pooled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the answer of pinckerman: It depends.

### The good

- It increases your chance of getting enough guppy items for a transformation. This happens because it might randomly select the curse pool to sell stuff, and this pool is mostly guppy items in greed mode. Or it might select the devil deal pool, which also contains guppy items.
- It might result in ridiculously good deals in the shop or in the treasure rooms.
- If you have already a gamebreaking run it'll add devil and angelroom items to the shop pool, and that's really good.

### The bad

- It lowers your chance of breaking the game because it lowers your chance for seeing blank card (blank card + two of diamonds and a battery for sale is infinite money in greed mode).
- You do not know what kind of items anything will contain, so no guaranteed shop pool items in the shop. Nor guaranteed boss room items in the bottom treasure room and in the shop. So you might run into very little or even no hp-increasing things at all.

So in the end it depends on what your goals are for the run. Do you want to play it safe and be assured that you'll keep finding hp items (since the boss room pool contains a lot of them)? Don't take it. Do you already have a way to infinite money? Take it, it'll help you get even more offensive items. Do you need that final guppy item? Take it if you like a gamble.

I personally always take it because I love the randomness, but it's up to you and your current situation. On a small note: do keep in mind that breaking the game and buying half a million items makes the game crash quite a lot, especially when you actually end up in combat. I had one run where I could fire *one* shot in the greed combat room, and then had to wait until everything was dead or my shot had subsided from being everywhere. Firing a second shot would crash the game. But at that point one shot would clear at least three or four waves.

Comment: (blank card + two of hearts and a battery for sale is infinite money in greed mode). :O How? I did not know this. Honestly, I haven't really used blank card before :3

Comment: I meant two of diamonds. Not two of hearts.

Comment: It's explained [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/250900/discussions/0/490124466464884248/) on what you need to do. Blank card can be pretty powerful. If you can combine it during a normal run with a rune that doubles stuff on the ground you're set. Or with the rune that rerolls items gives you basically a four-room D6.

Answer (score 5):

I think, and keep in mind I haven't played in a while, chaos would greatly impact the items within the two itemrooms on each floor. This would give you the chance to get angel or devil items for free or chose one for a key.

Answer (score 5):

It depends.

*Chaos* is a powerful item, because items can be chosen from random (and rare) Item Pools as Devil and Angel Pools. But the main drawback is, as *Chaos* does not actually mix or combine item pools, it is possible to quickly deplete smaller item pools. This means that, when it's chosen an item pool that is already depleted, it will not pull from a different pool and instead giving you only *Breakfast*.

As many Greed Mode item pools are small, *Chaos* tends to result in *Breakfast* more often during Greed Mode. So be careful.

Source, [Rebirth wikia](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Chaos).

Comment: Minor nitpick: It's not that Greed Mode item pools are small - they're actually almost the same as the regular mode. The main difference is that you cycle through the items much faster, which means you start seeing a lot of breakfasts much faster than you would in the regular game.

Comment: @MageXy They actually are smaller than usual in Greed Mode, for example the [Secret Room Greed Item Pool](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Secret_Room_(Greed_Mode_Item_Pool)) only has one item. The Curse Room Pool is also very small.